# Ip-failover and geolocalization

Tags: domain-name-system, failover, seo

I have a server (from OVH) located in France with French ip. However most of the people coming to my website are from Poland. From what I read having a Polish ip address could lead to better search engine positioning in my case.

So I ordered a Polish "failover-ip" from OVH which as they tell me is "routed to my server's (French) ip". How do I go from here?

Should I:

1. set up the failover ip as outlined here: http://help.ovh.co.uk/IpAlias ?
2. change my DNS setting so that my domain points to the failover-ip ?

Or do anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should do both. The first item is to let your server know that it now has an additional IP address. The second is obviously so that your web site can be reached by the failover IP.

Before you perform the step 2, you may want to verify the step 1 is indeed successful by connecting to your server via the failover IP (using SSH or using http:// to see if it reaches your server.)